# iPhone - adding views and landscape orientation

Tags: iphone

I got a problem with Cocoa touch and landscape orientation.

I instantiate my view from a .xib; i added in my view controller

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

to only allow landscape orientation.

This works find for the first view i add.. if I add a second view however it is rotated again like the landscape view is shown in portrait mode (rotated 90 degree counterclockwise).

I really don't know what is going on and can't find a workaround. I even tried to get behind what is happening just adding my view twice:

```
MainMenuViewController* controller = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview: controller.view];

MainMenuViewController* controller2 = [[MainMenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[window addSubview: controller2.view];


[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The view of controller is displayed correctly, while the view of controller2 is rotated by 90 degrees. Does anyone have an idea how this can happen? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you shoud put

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
  return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

also in your mainMenuViewController

Comment: that's exactly what i did.

the problem is, that the orientation works for the first instance. the second instance gets rotated by 90 degrees.

i now made a workaround by attaching a view between my window and my custom views that i change by code. this seems to work. nevertheless it's a strange behavior i don't understand.